# Вознаграждение за просмотр рекламы

Tags: android, реклама

Может кто-нибудь показать пример или поделиться ссылкой на ресурс, где объясняется как сделать рекламу, за просмотр которой будет получена награда.(Желательно через русскоязычный сервис с рекламой, например AdMob) Искал сам, но нахожу только как сделать баннеры и межстраничную рекламу.

Comment: https://www.ironsrc.com/

Comment: Вот AdMob-вская дока по видео с вознаграждением: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

Answer (score 1):

Пример. Открывается активность и пытается показать рекламу за вознаграждение. XML шаблон просто текстовое поле "Пожалуйста подождите".

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;


public class AdsVideo extends Activity{
    private RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.ads_video );

        rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener( new RewardedVideoAdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded(){
                if( rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded() ){
                    rewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened(){}

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted(){}

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed(){}

            @Override
            public void onRewarded( RewardItem rewardItem ){
                // реклама просмотрена, пользователь ожидает вознаграждение
                Toast.makeText( AdsVideo.this, android.R.string.ok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication(){}

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad( int i ){
                Toast.makeText( AdsVideo.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                finish();
            }
        } );

        rewardedVideoAd.loadAd( getString( R.string.adUnitId_video ), new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        rewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        rewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        rewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```